# Javascript to download contents from a folder of webpage

Tags: javascript, download, web-crawler, userscripts

I have access to a public folder of my website. which has number of files on it. Say the URL is

http://www.abc.com/step-b/Prints/

The above URL shows this when opened in a browser :

```
**Index of /step-b/Prints

    Name    Last modified   Size    Description
    Parent Directory         -
    L/  05-Jan-2006 23:59    -
    L2/ 05-Jan-2006 23:51    -
    R/  05-Jan-2006 23:41    -
    R2/ 05-Jan-2006 23:32    -
    Thumbs.db   30-Jan-2007 09:00    81K
    hpothb07.dat    27-Aug-2008 07:00    0
    hpothb07.tif    27-Aug-2008 07:00    0**
```

Now i wish to run a loop to go in every folder L,L2,R,R2 that goes and extracts some 200 files from it.

I do not have any clue how to start . And if even JS is best thing to do for the same.

Can anyone guide me or suggest me.. I do not desire the code but a guidance how to do the things.

Comment: If you desire guidance you may be in the wrong place. This is not a forum or a recruitment venue for mentoring, but a programming Q&A.

Comment: In first you write to userscript or some javascript in your browser only. And after you write any javascript code.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Wow.. a really long Handle.. anyways.. i just desire a hint.. i know this is a prog. QnA, but i believe it aint specific to only "write your code and take help" , i believe my question is of programming domain and thus fits here.

Comment: @gmunkhbaatarmn Yes i know .. reason i love JS is , it is really powerful and easy to incorporate on any hosting.

Comment: @typedef1: But it's not a question.

Comment: This is not a job for javascript/userscript.  Do this with a language like Python.  Search for how to scrape or crawl via Python, you'll find plenty of articles and examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the same origin policy it can be a bit difficult to perform what you want in JS (for example you can't download this page via AJAX).

But if you already know how to access the page, then you have to parse it. What you see in a browser is obviously an HTML code. So you need to know how to retrieve those folders names. If the HTML is based on tables, then this should not be hard.

Finally, when you parse the page and you have names of folders you need to know what is inside them. Probably the following url `http://www.abc.com/step-b/Prints/L2/` will tell you what's inside `L2`. If it won't then you can stop now, because it won't be possible to do it. :) Unless you somehow now how to retrieve the list of files in folder via http.

Next step in a loop you go through all folders and parse them just like before. And then you append file names to the end of urls like `http://www.abc.com/step-b/Prints/L2/myfile.txt` (it may fail to work - see previous comment). At this point you can easily download them.

Keep in mind that this is all theory and it depends on web server how it responses to requests. I can assure you that the task you want to perform won't be easy at all.